# How can I monitor a file and print out changes in the terminal (using inotify)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, inotify

I want to run a script that transfers the changes of a file to another file (like a log file) and also print it out in the terminal.
I would prefer using the inotify tool, but other suggestions are welcome as well :)

I tried using inotifywait with the -m prefix, but the commands after it don't run because inotifywait -m repeats itself continuously.
Using inotifywait without prefixes didn't help either.

```
...
inotifywait -m $file >> logfile.log 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `tee` filter, which will read the input from `inotfywait` and output both to the terminal, and also to a file.

```
inotifywait -m file | tee -a logfile.log
```

To run this in the background see below, but you will get `inotifywait` output to terminal whilst this command is running.

```
nohup inotifywait -m file | tee -a logfile.log &
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!! :)
But is it possible to run the command in the background (e.g. as a while loop) and execute other commands? Because right now, after I execute your command line, I cannot go on in my script. :/